# Scatterplots and R, having a difficult time

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot

I have a data set containing 13 attributes. I am using R.

1. I would like to generate a scatterplot for each pair of attributes (with properly labeled x and y axis), which will give me a total of 156 scatterplots.
2. I want all of these 156 scatterplots displayed in 1 jpeg/pdf file.
3. I also want to find the pair with the highest correlation coefficient.

How do I go about doing this? I am very confused.

Comment: Are you trying to create scatterplots for relationships between variables? This plot will look messy and be very hard to interpret.

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample data? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you Googled? [The `pairs` function does this.](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/graphics/html/pairs.html)

Comment: Check this link http://www.r-bloggers.com/scatterplot-matrices-in-r/

Comment: I am trying to create scatterplots for relationships between each combination of 2 variables.

Comment: Here is 1 data point 1,14.06,2.15,2.61,17.6,121,2.6,2.51,.31,1.25,5.05,1.06,3.58,1295 indices 0-12 are different attributes. I want to take all the data points and compare based on a different pair of attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are actually quite straightforward.

```
plot(mtcars)
```

[image]

And to save it:

```
png()
plot(mtcars)
dev.off()
```

And to get the correlations:

```
cor(mtcars)
            mpg        cyl       disp         hp        drat         wt
mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620 -0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.68117191 -0.8676594
cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000  0.9020329  0.8324475 -0.69993811  0.7824958
disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000  0.7909486 -0.71021393  0.8879799
hp   -0.7761684  0.8324475  0.7909486  1.0000000 -0.44875912  0.6587479
drat  0.6811719 -0.6999381 -0.7102139 -0.4487591  1.00000000 -0.7124406
wt   -0.8676594  0.7824958  0.8879799  0.6587479 -0.71244065  1.0000000
qsec  0.4186840 -0.5912421 -0.4336979 -0.7082234  0.09120476 -0.1747159
vs    0.6640389 -0.8108118 -0.7104159 -0.7230967  0.44027846 -0.5549157
am    0.5998324 -0.5226070 -0.5912270 -0.2432043  0.71271113 -0.6924953
gear  0.4802848 -0.4926866 -0.5555692 -0.1257043  0.69961013 -0.5832870
carb -0.5509251  0.5269883  0.3949769  0.7498125 -0.09078980  0.4276059
            qsec         vs          am       gear        carb
mpg   0.41868403  0.6640389  0.59983243  0.4802848 -0.55092507
cyl  -0.59124207 -0.8108118 -0.52260705 -0.4926866  0.52698829
disp -0.43369788 -0.7104159 -0.59122704 -0.5555692  0.39497686
hp   -0.70822339 -0.7230967 -0.24320426 -0.1257043  0.74981247
drat  0.09120476  0.4402785  0.71271113  0.6996101 -0.09078980
wt   -0.17471588 -0.5549157 -0.69249526 -0.5832870  0.42760594
qsec  1.00000000  0.7445354 -0.22986086 -0.2126822 -0.65624923
vs    0.74453544  1.0000000  0.16834512  0.2060233 -0.56960714
am   -0.22986086  0.1683451  1.00000000  0.7940588  0.05753435
gear -0.21268223  0.2060233  0.79405876  1.0000000  0.27407284
carb -0.65624923 -0.5696071  0.05753435  0.2740728  1.00000000
```

And to get the highest correlation is a bit more tricky:

```
cor_values = cor(mtcars)
diag(cor_values) = NA   # Set diagonal to NA or else that will be the highest correlation
which(cor_values == max(cor_values, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
disp   3   2
cyl    2   3
```

Which in this case involves the `disp` and `cyl` variables.

Comment: I like to use `plot(mtcars,gap=0)`

Comment: @BenBolker that is a very nice addition indeed.